# auto detect tag within a text

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, tags, keyword

Does there is any library or algorithm that can do auto detection of tags in a text (ignoring the usual words of the chosen language)?

Something like this:

```
string[] keywords = GetKeyword("Your order is num #0123456789")
```

and keywords[] would contain "order" and "#0123456789" ...?
Does it exist? Or the user will select by himself all the tags of every document all the time? :?

Comment: Have you looked a regular expressions?

Comment: Are the keywords you want to filter from a given whitelist?

Comment: Yes, and i would use it if there no other way to automatic find words without specifying any rules. (i know, my query is probably stupid... :$ )

Comment: Could you store an instance of each word that is fed into your program in a database table then increment a counter for each, then over time the most *used* words would be at the top of the table. That doesn't specify what is 'important' though. Your definition of 'important' must some how be defined in your code, possibly a usage counter plus length of word, the longer the word the more 'important'? either way probably beyond a quick answer anyone could provide on SO I am guessing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a lot of different algorithms can be used. Some of them are simple another are super complex. I can suggest you the next basic way:

1. Split all text into array of words.
2. Remove stop words from the array. (Goole "stop words list" to get full list of stop words.)
3. Walk through the array and calculate count of each word.
4. Sort words in accordance with their 'weight' in the array.
5. Choose necessary amount of tags.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I misunderstood the question. If you want to look for specific words, the algorithm will depend on you strings. For example, you can use string.Split() to generate an array of words from one string, and then work with that, like this:

```
string[] words = string.Split("Your order is num #0123456789");
string orderNumber = "";
if(words.Contains("order") && w.StartsWith("#").Count > 0)
{
    orderNumber = words.Where(w=>w.StartsWith("#").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This will first generate an array of words from "Your order is num #0123456789" , then if it contains the word "order" it will wind a word that starts with "#" and select that;

Comment: I have not been quite understandable sorry. I do not want to look for specific words in a text. I want to automatically detect the important words of a given text.

Comment: @Vloz What is an "important word"?

Comment: For example, the words that Google will automatically keep for this web page. Recognizing important word in a text is possible, but there is maybe not open solution for this... :$

Comment: @Vloz: A lot of the time in designing algorithms like this goes into defining what is an "important words". Google most likely spent at least 50 percent of their time defining such terms, the implementation is not that hard once you really know what you want. Programming is often about very clearly and carefully defining terms, so unless you give a clear definition of your terms, no one will be able to help you with your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(string keyword in keywords) { // where keywords is a List<string>
    if ("Your order is num #0123456789".Contains(keyword)) {
        keywordsPresent.Add(keyword); // where keywordsPresent is a List<string>
    }
}

return keywordsPresent;
```

What the above does is not cater for your #0123456789, for that add some more logic to find the index of the # or something...